# Using LIKE for multiple columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server to search through multiple columns (over 20 in reality) in my table containing part of a certain value, but I keep getting the error

> 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

I am running SQL Server 2017 and the function should be available, so I'm not sure if there's an error in my query or if something else is causing the error.

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE 
   CONCAT(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8) LIKE '%val%'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sample data would be nice.

Comment: Are you sure you want your select to return data when e.g. col1 = 'v', col2='a' and col3 = 'l' ?

Comment: Note that `'somewhere' || 'wolfenstein' like '%wherewolf%'` returns _true_.

Comment: Exactly my point earlier. I love the joke though :)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504757/sql-search-multiple-columns-using-like

Comment: Your syntax looks correct, are you sure that you are on 2017?  Select @@version  also what is your compatibility level >= 110  ?

Comment: To check compatibility   select name, compatibility_level from sys.databases

Comment: @jarlh - no it doesn't. It uses the non standard `+`

Comment: @MartinSmith, it doesn't? Not even more recent versions?

Comment: No. More recent versions have the CONCAT function though.

Comment: Alright, I've now deleted my incorrect suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+`:

```
where (col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 + col6 + col7 + col8) like '%val%'
```

This assumes that all the columns are non-NULL string columns.

If they could be `NULL` or are not strings, then you need explicit conversion:

```
where (coalesce(convert(nvarchar(max), col1), '') +
       coalesce(convert(nvarchar(max), col2), '') +
       . . .
       coalesce(convert(varchar(max), col8), '') +
      ) like '%val%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another option, however I suspect `concat()` or Gordon's (+1) would be more performant

```
Select *
 From  YourTable A
 Where (select A.* for xml raw) like '%YourSearch%'
```

> **EDIT**

Just for fun, I ran a comparison of the the `concat()` vs the xml approach.  The sample was 25K rows with 101 columns.  The average of 5 runs for `concat` was 886ms while the xml was 1.162.

Clearly `concat()` is the winner, but the xml approach was not horrible, and may be another option in a discovery phase.

Comment: I like your answer @John (+1)

Comment: @PawelCzapski Thanks for the grin :).   See EDIT for a quick comparison and comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd tweak Gordon's solution slightly to insert some delimiting character  between the concatenated terms to avoid scenarios where the end of the one value and the start of the next combine to give you a match.

```
where (col1 + '|' + col2 + '|' + col3 + '|' + col4 + '|' + col5 + '|' + col6 + '|' + col7 + '|' + col8) like '%val%'
```

Comment: Seems like this should really be a comment on Gordon's answer to me. Also, I never use single character delimiters (could be part of the data); I choose something more like '[DELIM]'.